# Laravel 10 Eloquent belongsTo not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

Using Laravel 10 and trying to get a belongsTo relationship to work and it's not working. Basically a Fragment has one FragmentGroup while a FragmentGroup has many Fragments.

I'm using it this way and it's giving me null:

```
$fragment = Fragment::find(1);
return $fragment->fragmentGroup->name;
```

```
class Fragment extends Model {

    public function fragmentGroup(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(FragmentGroup:class, 'FragmentID');
    }
}


class FragmentGroup extends Model  {

    public function medicine_type(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Fragment:class, 'FragmentGroupID');
    }
}
```

Database structure

```
Fragment:
   FragmentID
   FragmentGroupID
   Name

FragementGroup
   FragmentGroupID
   Name
```

Comment: How do you even use them? Do you use them in your eloquent? What do you mean not working? Error message showing? No data displayed? Wrong Data displayed?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth I updated my question with how I'm using it.

Comment: should have been `$fragment->fragmentGroup()->name`, right? keep in mind its lazy loading, if you need to load a bunch of `Fragment`'s `FragmentGroup` use a `with`.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using the method is not correct.

Anyways, to use it you would need to change

```
$fragment = Fragment::find(1);
```

to

```
$fragment = Fragment::with('fragmentGroup')->find(1); # or maybe with('fragment_group')
```

$fragment should now have `fragment_group` as part of the collection.
You can check if you `dd($fragment);`

If you can see `fragment_group` but it has blank array/object as its value, then check the methods used inside model.

Comment: There's no need to do this; it will be fetched from the database afterwards if it isn't included initially. It's a good practice when fetching multiple model instances, but makes no difference to performance or anything else in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, there is a typing mistake in **`FragmentGroup:class`**. It should be **`FragmentGroup::class`**.

Also, you can pass the `foreign_key` and `local_key` to further specify.

Your function should be:

```
class Fragment extends Model {

    public function fragmentGroup(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(FragmentGroup::class, 'FragmentID', 'FragmentGroupID');
    }
}


class FragmentGroup extends Model  {

    public function medicine_type(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Fragment::class, 'FragmentGroupID', 'FragmentID');
    }
}
```

I think it will be solve your problem.

Comment: If this were the problem, they would receive fatal parse errors on the screen, not returned value of null. Probably it is just a typo in posting the question.